# Qt using a Linux shell application - Must be connected to a terminal

Tags: linux, qt, ubuntu, console, terminal

To start sorry for my bad English.

I'm trying to code an application that interacts with VirtualGL. The problem is when i use a simple `QProcess` to launch the code the fallowing error appears: *"Must be connected to a terminal."*

Is there a way to simulate the use of the terminal in a Qt application?... Or (better for me) is there a way, like in Ubuntu Update's, show the Terminal output in the same GUI window?

Or should I use another language like Java, python or GTK+?

Answer (score 0):

I am just guessing that your problem is caused by ssh not attached to a terminal. Use **ssh -t** parameter to start the virtual gl. Also [this](https://serverfault.com/questions/21806/how-can-i-launch-a-screen-session-with-a-command-over-ssh-on-a-remote-server-from) question may be helpful. Good luck.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answer but i'm not sure if it is what i want :S... I have been trying it and this error always appears : ssh: connect to host BodyAsus port 22: Connection refused... I would need a easy (without background work from the user) to run virtual gl.